# My scorecounter won't update on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I click on my #playOne or #playerTwo buttons the span in the h1 does not update in the browser. I also get no errors on my console.

```js
const p1Display = document.querySelector('#p1Counter');
const p2Display = document.querySelector('#p2Counter');
const p1 = document.querySelector('#playerOne');
const p2 = document.querySelector('#playerTwo');
const reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
let scoreOne = 0;
let scoreTwo = 0;

p1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scoreOne += 1;
  p1Display.textContent = scoreOne;
});
p2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scoreTwo += 1;
  p2Counter.textContent = scoreTwo;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ping Pong</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="p1Counter">0</span> to <span id="p2Counter">0</span></h1>
  <button id="playerOne">+1 Player One</button>
  <button id="playerTwo">+1 Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>

  <source src="app.js" type="">
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried changing id tags to see if it helps but nothing.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me

Comment: @MichaelM. True, but I wonder *how that's possible* because the contents of `#p2Counter` is set but the variable `p2Counter` is not defined anywhere in the code (PS @KymCiel: I think that is your bug). Seems like a glitch (or hidden feature?) where HTML elements with an `id` become defined as variables under the same name in the snippet JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your html file, you are calling your js with source tag.
You should have: `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you! New to coding so now ill try to be more careful from now on.

Comment: don't worry, take it easy and have fun in a few years you'll be looking back at this and have a laugh :)